# Cypress - doesn't find table elements

Tags: jquery, cypress

Dear stackoverflow members,
i have an issue testing our webpage in cypress.io
I am iterating with $().each() function in jquery, and trying to find an specific element in a table row and also trying to make it " highlighted or ' selected' " .
The crazy thing is when i try in the conditional part like :

```
let number = $("#idOfSomething").text(); // Here i store the text from a dynamic label
                                         // which get its value from db  

if( Cypress.$(this).find('td:eq(1):contains("' + number+ '")').length > 0 ){
  // nothing found 
}
```

--------------or------------------

```
else if (Cypress.$(this).find('td:eq(1)').text() == number ){
// nothing found
}
```

---

But if i try to put the value in the conditional part HARD CODED then it finds it

```
 if (Cypress.$(this).find('td:eq(1)').text() == "xy123" ){
    cy.log(number)  // prints "xy123"
    }
```

---

Why is that ???

---

Another thing is when i try to loop over the same table with the same function like above
and the table is longer than a page, then i scroll down to the bottom of the table with this function :

```
cy.get("#myTable").scrollTo("bottomLeft");
```

while it loops over every element,
it doesnt find that element if it is not on the screen at first before the function scrolls down.
I mean, if i type a number like "1" in the condition part :

```
if(Cypress.$(this).find('td:eq(1)').text() == 1 ){
// here it finds the entry 1 in the table, because it is at the first page directly,
```

// but lets say a type 50 instead of 1  --> now the 50 isnt at the screen.
   // cypress scrolls down ... I SEE THE NUMBER 50 ON THE SCREEN , BUT CYPRESS WONT see it.
}

i tried also to click on the table header so the numbers gets DESC ...so 50 is at first ...wont work either .
I tried also to scroll down to the bottom via an offset xy..wont work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who has the same issue ->

just use a cypress build-in function like this:

```
cy.contains(yourVariableName).scrollIntoView().click();
```

here you say to cypress ->
first  : look at the whole DOM and find this element
second : scroll into that element if it is not in the view
third  : click on that element

FYI : with this function ...you dont have to scroll down step by step to find that element.
You dont have to check if there is a scrollbar either.

after these steps you can do anything with it.

Have a nice day

Comment: This doesn't work if the element is hidden and it has scroll down

Comment: I can verify.  This is not working for me either on a Material table where there are items not visible that you can scroll to within the table.